# ASP.NET MVC - Having a delete button per row when displaying results based on user-specified search criteria

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In a single ASP.NET Razor view, I want to display 10 textboxes (the user will enter various search criteria into these), and then when the user submits the form (presses a Search button) and the server processes the action, I want to display the results in the same view.

I have the above working.

Now, along with the results, I want the user to have the ability to delete a specific row (I need to specify the values of 3 fields from that row in order to uniquely identify the row on the backend, i.e. the primary key of the table is composed of 3 columns). And after deleting, I want to use the same criteria as the user specified earlier (in the 10 textboxes) and re-display the results.

How do I do the above?

I can have a single form cover the entire page, and add a separate INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT button for each row, but how do I pass back data that indicates which row the user deleted?

I can also have a separate form for each row, and have INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN fields that include values from that row, but then, how do I get access to the search criteria that was originally used?

Comment: option 2 would be the conventional approach and much easier to implement, but if you need to persist the search results, maybe store the criteria in the session or something. or, more user-friendly, do the delete via ajax, so you don't have to refresh the page at all.

Comment: Using ajax would give much better performance and you would not have to re-load the view (just remove the associated row from the table). Just add some `data-*` attributes to your buttons to identify the record.